# Triangle x's project in C

Tags: c

I have been given a project to make a triangular staircase of x's where each row after the next has one additional x.

I have so far created a staircase where each row has the same x but I want to add an addition x for each one.  my code should look something like this:

```
x    
xx    
xxx    
xxxx
```

and so on..

my code so far is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int rows,columns,num;
    char x;

    printf("Please input the number of stairs\n");
    scanf("%i",&num);

    for(rows = 1, columns = 1; rows <= num && columns <= num; rows ++, columns ++)
        printf("x\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a double loop to build the triangle of x's.  The first loop iterates over rows and the second loop adds the correct number of x's to each row.

```
int main(void) {
    int num;

    printf("Please input the number of stairs\n");
    scanf("%i",&num);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
        for (int c=1; c <= i; ++c) printf("x");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int rows,columns,num;

    printf("Please input the number of stairs\n");
    scanf("%i",&num);

    for(rows = 1; rows <= num; rows ++)
    {
        for(columns = 1;columns <= rows; columns++)
        {
            printf("x");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```